# Insert in child and parent JSON Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postman, spring-data-rest

I have 3 entities in my spring boot App data rest, Appusers, Teacher, and Student

1. Appusers

   ```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
   @Column(name= "appuserId", updatable=false)
   private Long appuserId;     
   @Column(name = "username")
   private String username;

   @Column(name = "fullname")
   private String fullName;

   @Column(name = "email")
   private String email;   

   @Column(name = "password")
   private String password;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appuser")
   private Teacher teacher;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appuser")
   private Student student;
   ```
2. Teacher

   ```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "teacherId" , updatable = false)
   private Long teacherId;

   @Column(name= "firstname")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "lastname")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name="designation")
   private String designation;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "appuserId", nullable = true)
   private Appuser appuser;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true ,mappedBy="teacher")
   @JsonIgnore
   private List<Course> courses;
   ```
3. Student

   ```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
   @Column(name= "studentId", updatable=false)
   private Long studentId;

   @Column(name = "firstName")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "lastName")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "enrolledSince")
   private String enrolledSince;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "appuserId", nullable = false)
   private Appuser appuser;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="student")
   @JsonIgnore
   private List<CourseStudent> courseStudents;
   ```

i can insert in appusers table using json format in postman and it goes well. but when i try to insert in teacher or student table the result in appusers is null. it shouldnt be null because teacher and student foreign key to appusers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not happen. When you save a teacher or a student you should specify appuser which is already in the database. And use appuserId instead Appuser, which is quite enough to identify to which appuser it belongs.

You can get your appuser after you save a teacher or a student and do request with join to the database.

Comment: but how to do inserting teacher and automatically inserting appuser? like in json

Comment: You don't have to do this. It is a bad pattern. Do as I answered. But if you want, in your RestController method first save appuser, get appuserId via your service method and after that save teacher or student. You can't save teacher before saving appuser, because you can't specify appuserId. First get it as I described.

Answer (score 1):

when you try to insert in teacher or student table, please make sure  that  you are setting the value to appuser while persisting.

```
Student std =new Student();
// create an object of appuser,set its vaue and assign it to student object
 Appuser ap = new Appuser();
 // assigning values to the appuser object as ap.setfullname="...";... so on
 std.setAppuser=ap;
```

now persist this student object the entries will be reflected in the mapped table 
or you can set the id of appuser in std object that is already persisted .